# How to get name of just created captcha image?

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I have written the code for creating the captcha in controller(Codeigniter) and I have to send the image url as a response from JSON to frontend. When I echo the cap['image'], the image is getting print successfully. So, how can get the name of just created captcha so that I can append the name of captcha to $img_url and send as JSON response.

```
$captch = array(
            'img_path' => $img_path,
            'img_url' => $img_url,
            'img_width' => '200',
            'img_height' => '50',
            'expiration' => '300',

        );

        $cap = create_captcha($captch);
        echo $cap['image'];
```

Comment: Is there any method that can return the name of an captcha image?

Comment: you will get name of captcha image using `$cap['time']`  and check extension of images in uploaded folder(it may be jpg)